# Is this BCNF convertion correct?

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization

I got a problem to translate relation Shipping into relations in BCNF. So first of all I had to convert that to 3NF. So here what I got.

Shipping(Ship,Capacity,Date,Cargo,Value) PK: Ship,Date.

FDs : Ship-> Capacity , (Ship,Date) -> Cargo , (Capacity,Cargo) ->Value.

Here what I got when converted to 3NF.

R1(Ship,Date,Cargo) PK: Ship,Date
R2(Ship,Capacity) PK: Ship
R3(Calacity,Cargo,Value) PK: Calacity, Cargo

So first and second satisfies BCNF since

1. Ship,Date is the primary key of R1 and only available FD of R1 is ,
   Ship,Date -> Cargo and
2. Ship is the primary key of R2 and only available FD of R2 is Ship-> Capacity.

But R3 is not because Cargo and Capacity is not a key of Shipping. So I have to make another relation R4 such that,

R4 (Ship,Capacity,Cargo)

So please can someone verify my result? I'm studying BCNF these days.

Comment: Could you please explain that algorithm? I cannot understand that when making new relations. As an example in this relation is Ship->Capacity FD in BCNF?

Comment: Shipping relation's PK is Ship and date.

Comment: There is a standard algorithm to decompose to BCNF. Determining whether a relation is *in* BCNF is a different algorithm/test. (And it's part of the preceding algorithm.) (Find a definition of BCNF.) Get as far as you can then post a question describing where you got to, giving what references you are using, and asking for what you need to be unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

The standard algorithm to decompose to BCNF takes any relation. There is no need for you to decompose to 3NF first. Google 'BCNF algorithm' to find a college/university textbook or presentation. Although https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139322/decompose-this-relation-into-bcnf seems to quote one.

PS Your reasoning about "only available FDs" is unsound. You are given some set of FDs that is presumably a cover. (Ie only the FDs that follow from them hold.) That means other FDs can hold that only involve some of the attributes. So in a component that doesn't use the other attributes that FD must hold--even if it was not in the cover. You need to learn how to calculate a 'minimal cover' and then how to calculate the 'closure of a set of attributes' given a minimal cover. Then when you drop attributes and the FDs that hold are the ones in the closure of the set of the remaining attributes, you have a cover for them.  Note that the algorithm in the link above involves repeatedly finding a FD that holds (sometimes for the original relation, and sometimes for a component of it) from the closure of the set of FDs. Not just some cover you started with.

PPS PKs are irrelevant. Candidate keys matter. A PK is just some CK that you picked to call PK.